# How to select all visible <li> elements with children? (jquery selector)

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html structure that looks like:

```
<li style="display: block;">
    <label>..
    <input>..
    <ol>
        <li style="display: block;">
            <label>..
            <input>..
            <ol>
                <li style="display: none;"> <!--Don't select this-->
                    <label>..
                    <input>..
                    <ol>
                        <li style="display: block;"> <!--Don't select this-->
                            <leaf>..
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
            </ol>
            <ol>
                <li style="display: block;"> <!--Don't select this-->
                    <leaf>..
                </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
```

I want to select all `<li>` element that 
1) is visible
2) is not a leaf node

I started with

```
$("li:visible").each(function() {...})
```

but I can't find any jquery selector (or css selector) that excludes element without any children. Please help.

NOTE: This question is completely different from the suggested duplication. I am not looking to select all elements without children. Plus, I have an additional condition (visible). My title was wrong and misleading, now revised.

Comment: That's not valid html ... `<li>` can't be direct child of another `<li>`

Comment: Invalid HTML structure. First improve your HTML, answer would be found after.

Comment: Still not really clear what you are looking for. Only the visible children of the first level `<ol>` shown?

Comment: @charlietfl All I want is to select all <li> element that has children and is visible.

Answer (score -1):

Fix your html to have `<ul>` as parent of `<li>` as it is currently invalid

Then try

```
$('li:visible:has(ol)').each(function() {...})
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I think the OP want all visible `li` which are not themselves children of an li.

Comment: @Moob well that's not what question says.

Comment: Please take a look at the updated question again.

Comment: updated selector should be what you want